# Can a Kibana Canvas Markdown Element Display a Total of a Column?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, metricbeat

I have a Markdown Element on a Kibana canvas with the Expression Syntax:

```
filters group="default"
| essql 
  query="SELECT host.hostname, (last(system.memory.actual.used.bytes, \"@timestamp\") as memoryused, last(system.memory.total, \"@timestamp\") as memory from \"metricbeat*\" where system.memory.actual.used.bytes is not null group by host.hostname"
| head 1
| mapColumn "memoryused" expression={getCell "memoryused" | math expression="value" | formatNumber "0,0"}
| mapColumn "memory" expression={getCell "memory" | math expression="value" | formatNumber "0,0"}
| markdown "
{{#each rows}}
 **{{memoryused}}** of **{{memory}}** GB
{{/each}}" 
  font={font family="Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'" size=16 align="center" color="#000000" weight="normal" underline=false italic=false}
| render containerStyle={containerStyle}
```

The essql query used here returns:

**host.hostname**  |  **memoryused**  |  **memory**

ip1 |  2   |  10

ip2 |  10   |  100

ip3 |  20   |  100

The markdown element as it is currently will display whatever the first row of the result is, so usually:

"2 of 10 GB"

What can I change **in this markdown element** about the expression syntax, or query, to get the **total** of these 2 columns and have the end result display:

"32 of 210 GB"